# Less - How to insert an @variable into property (as opposed to the value)

Tags: css, less

In less.js, I'm able to replace values with variables with no problems.

```
@gutter: 20px;
margin-left:e(%("-%d"), @gutter);
```

When trying to replace properties with variables, I get errors. How would I perform the following in Less?

```
@gutter: 20px;
@direction: left;
e(%("margin-%d"), @direction):e(%("-%d"), @gutter);
```

Comment: or use SCSS where this is possible (writing this out of frustration that it's not in LESS, without being verbose and creating a rule for every possible parameter interpolation which is obviously limiting)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to Alvivi for the solution and research (you get the reward for that). I decided to add the following as the actual answer since this is a real way to set it up instead of looking at .blah() pseudo code..

Here's a real strategy for setting it up:

```
@gutter: 20px;
@dir: left;
@dirOp: right;
```

then create mixins to enhance margin and padding like so:

```
.margin(left, @dist:@gutter) {
    margin-left:@dist;
}
.margin(right, @dist:@gutter) {
    margin-right:@dist;
}
.padding(left, @dist:@gutter) {
    padding-left:@dist;
}
.padding(right, @dist:@gutter) {
    padding-right:@dist;
}
.lr(left, @dist: 0) {
    left: @dist;
}
.lr(right, @dist: 0) {
    right: @dist;
}
```

.. then you can just

```
#selector {
    .margin(@dir);
}
```

or

```
#selector {
    .margin(@dirOp, 10px);
}
```

all together:

```
#selector {
    .margin(@dir);
    .margin(@dirOp, 50px);
    .padding(@dir, 10px);
    .padding(@dirOp);
    float:@dir;
    text-align:@dirOp;
    position:absolute;
    .lr(@dir);
}
```

Easy breezy LTR/RTL with LESS! Woot!

Comment: That works. I really wish we could just do something like this : `.margin(@dir:top, @dist: 10px) { (~"margin-@{dir}"): @dist; }`.

Answer (score 2):

Escaping, as says the [documentation](http://lesscss.org/#-escaping), is used to create CSS values (not properties).

There is a discussion with some workarounds [here](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues#issue/36). One would be using [parametric mixins](http://lesscss.org/#-parametric-mixins). For example:

```
.g ()       { /* Common properties */ }
.g (right)  { margin-right: e(...) } 
.g (left)   { margin-left: e(...) }
```

Comment: an interesting strategy, but it would leave half of the generated selector/prop/values unused. I was looking for more of a way to do an if else statement that would only generate one property. I know you can use backticks (`\`4 + 4\``) to eval js. Maybe there's some sneaky way to get if/else into a .less file?